# Use of Subquery in Informix for Left Outer Join

Tags: subquery, informix

I have inherited a slow query in Informix.  I suspect part of the slowness is due to the use of subqueries to do left outer joins.  Here is a sample of the code:

FROM intide_rec AS IDE

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT idp_cmpy_id, idp_idc_ctl_no, idp_itm_ctl_no, idp_brh, idp_invt_typ, idp_frm, idp_grd, idp_size, idp_fnsh, idp_whs, idp_mill, idp_heat, idp_tag_no, idp_num_size1, idp_num_size2, idp_num_size3, idp_num_size4, idp_num_size5, idp_wdth, idp_lgth, idp_idia, idp_odia, idp_ga_size, idp_ohd_mat_val, idp_ohd_pcs, idp_ohd_wgt, idp_invt_sts, idp_invt_qlty, idp_bgt_for, idp_ownr_id FROM intidp_rec) AS IDP ON (IDE.ide_cmpy_id = IDP.idp_cmpy_id AND IDE.ide_idc_ctl_no = IDP.idp_idc_ctl_no)

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT prm_pep, prm_frm, prm_grd, prm_size, prm_fnsh FROM inrprm_rec) AS PRM ON
(IDP.idp_frm = PRM.prm_frm AND IDP.idp_grd = PRM.prm_grd AND IDP.idp_size = PRM.prm_size AND IDP.idp_fnsh = PRM.prm_fnsh)

Notice that the subqueries are simply retrieving columns.  There is no manipulation of the columns.  What is odd to me is why there are SELECT statements, i.e. subqueries, here.

Why not just remove the subqueries, move the columns out of the subqueries and into the main SELECT statement since there is no manipulation of columns and write the joins like this:

FROM intide_rec AS IDE

LEFT OUTER JOIN intidp_rec AS IDP ON (IDE.ide_cmpy_id = IDP.idp_cmpy_id AND IDE.ide_idc_ctl_no = IDP.idp_idc_ctl_no)

LEFT OUTER JOIN inrprm_rec AS PRM ON (IDP.idp_frm = PRM.prm_frm AND IDP.idp_grd = PRM.prm_grd AND IDP.idp_size = PRM.prm_size AND IDP.idp_fnsh = PRM.prm_fnsh)

What are your thoughts on the original code and subqueries vs the way I have rewritten the code?  Is it inefficient from a performance perspective?  Or is it acceptable from a performance perspective?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

One way to provide some answer is to analyze the output from SET EXPLAIN ON for the two queries.  Ideally, there shouldn't be a difference between the query plans. If the query plans are demonstrably 'the same' or 'equivalent', then the optimizer is doing its stuff well.  Determining that they are equivalent may be harder than either of us would like.  However, if there is a major difference in the query plans, the subqueries probably are slower and your rewrite should be at least as fast as the original and probably faster.  Also, remember that query plans are only indicative of what the optimizer thinks will happen — time the different queries on production data as well.

You don't mention which version of Informix you're using or which platform you're using it on.  It probably doesn't matter and it must be a relatively recent version to support the LEFT OUTER JOIN notation (this millennium rather than the last, at any rate).  However, it is beneficial to state that.  Note that only versions 12.10 and 14.10 are under support unless you've made special arrangements with IBM or HCL.